# Github repository rename issue

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I have a repository that was private and wanted to make some files public. Unfortunately, I didn't find a good way to do this so I renamed the old repo from NAME to NAME_dev. I then copied the files from the dev repo into a new repo called NAME which was public from the get-go.

Here's my problem: Github Desktop seems to be confused by this new public repo. When I clone the  public repo with it, it puts it into the right directory (user/GitHub/NAME) but it's cloning the contents of NAME_dev.

I re-did the initial process, this time initialising a new repo with GitHub Desktop called NAME, and manually selected each file I wanted to go in, without copying entire folders. Same problem. I deleted the entire local Github folder, redid everything, same problem. I made a new repo NAMEOS, put everything in, then renamed it back to NAME, same problem. I tried naming the dev version NAMEprivate in case the _dev was causing issues, same problem. I'm sure there's something I've done wrong but I can't seem to find how to fix this. Perhaps some hidden file in the private version still has the first name it received.

Either way, I need to have a public repo with the name NAME, with only certain files made public.

Any thoughts?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you push to a repository, you push all versions of every file (all commits) of that branch to that repository.

If you remove a file from the repository, it is still visible.

Git supports multiple remote repositories but if you push to one, you publish your whole work on your branch to that repository.

If you want to have multiple repositories but hide some files in one of them, you can do this by just creating different branches but the moment you merge from a "private" branch into a "public" branch and push it, you will publish every state of the "private" branch, too.

You can also use different local repositories and every time you commit to the repository that links to the public remote, you copy the files before committing.

If you don't need the private repository any more, you can just create a `.gitignore` file stating what files are not committed.
However, you need to either remove the old local repository (the `.git` directory) or remove those sensible files from the history using a command like `git filter-branch`.

I am not quite sure what you mean with GitHub Desktop being confused but the directory you clone to might just already exist with the content of your dev-repository or the "public" repository has tge content of the dev-repository.

Comment: Hi dan1st, thanks for the reply!

I appreciate the ways in which to make some things public and some private but it does seem that the easiest (surprisingly) is to have one public repo and one private repo. 

The challenge seems to be the fact that the private repo used to have the name of what I want the public repo to be. This is my issue. I have cleared the target directory a few times and this doesn't change much. 

This must be something with how git remembers which files are associated with a repo.

Comment: Do you use the same local repository? (Same directory)

Comment: My plan was to have two different local repositories, in two different directories. I.e. Github/NAME/ and Github/NAMEprivate. I renamed the dev branch to NAMEprivate, which worked fine. But when I clone NAME from github desktop, it automatically calls it Github/NAME, but fills it with the content of NAMEprivate.

Comment: Did you specify the correct url? Anyways, you can clone it using `git clone <repository url>` from the CLI, this is more reliable.

Comment: Wow, doing it from the CLI fills it with the right content! Thank you! Strangely though, Github Desktop still refers to it as NAMEprivate. It lists the wrong url, the wrong user/reponame listing, but the right directory, and doesn't recognise any differences in files. Do you have any idea how to fix that part?

Comment: You may be able to remove that repository from GitHub Desktop.

Comment: Doing so, and then re-pointing to it by pressing "add existing repository" still shows the same strange behaviour. Happy to ignore this if it's not worth fixing. Uninstalling and re-installing github desktop shows the same thing.

Comment: I think it saves this in a da directory or the registry...